# How to print all value of one column in list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, called list_out. I want to access values of the 2nd column in the list(i want acsses to '313','321'and '365'). list_out is following:

```
list_out = [('2240', '313', {'Sign': 1}),
            ('2240', '321', {'Sign': 1}), 
            ('2240', '365', {'Sign': -1})]
```

I used :

```
print (list_out[0])
```

out:

```
('2240', '313', {'Sign': 1})
```

then i used:

```
print (list_out[0][1])
```

out:

```
313
```

above code, return value of 2nd columns in one row in the list(only '313'). I want access to the value of 2nd column in all row.
Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(list(zip(*list_out))[1])
```

Output:

```
('313', '321', '365')
```

OR:

```
print([i[1] for i in list_out])
```

Output:

```
['313', '321', '365']
```

Comment: Nice answer. voted up.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar Thanks, Happy it's good

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @mina Please accept my answer if it works

Answer (score 2):

```
list_out = [('2240', '313', {'Sign': 1}), ('2240', '321', {'Sign': 1}), 
('2240', '365', {'Sign': -1})]
column2=[j for _,j,_ in list_out]
```

**output**

```
['313', '321', '365']
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Upvoted... Could be better written as `[j for _,j,*_ in list_out]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(map(itemgetter(1), list_out))

# ['313', '321', '365']
```

Or via sequence unpacking:

```
_, res, _ = zip(*list_out)

print(res)

# ('313', '321', '365')
```

If you do not wish to unpack non-required columns:

```
from itertools import islice

res = next(islice(zip(*L), 1, None))
```